# Expanded option on true on virtual field make error 500

Tags: forms, symfony

On a form, i have a problem with a virtual field...

When expanded option is set to false no no worries but if i set the option to true (to display pretty radio button) given an error 500 :

> Neither the property "0" nor one of the methods "get0()", "0()",
>   "is0()", "has0()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class...

This is the offending add :

```
->add('formGame', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'official' => 'Officielles',
        'unofficial' => 'Non officielles'
    ),
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => true,
    'inherit_data' => true,
    'label' => 'Formes de jeu'
))
```

I find no info about this error ... someone an idea ?

Comment: what do you mean with "virtual"? You mean a field that is not mapped to underlying entity?

Comment: exactly, the "inherit_data' => true" option define this... it replace "virtual" option since Symfony 2.3

Comment: No, wait, I just wanted to know if formGame property is a property of underlying object or not, not if is "inherited" from the underlying object. Is pretty different.

Comment: Ok, sorry, formGame is not a property of underlying object indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that, for this particular kind of "tasks" you need `mapped => false` and not the inherit option

So

```
->add('formGame', 'choice', array( 
    'choices' => array(
         'official' => 'Officielles', 
         'unofficial' => 'Non officielles' ), 
    'multiple' => false, 
    'expanded' => true, 
    'mapped' => false,
    'label' => 'Formes de jeu' ))
```

Comment: @J1v3 remember to mark the answer if this is the solution